# How to get noun phrases without "the", "a", or other adjectives?

Tags: spacy, phrase

spaCy shows "the adipose tissue" and "chronic energy imbalance". However, I'd like the noun phrase to be made of only nouns instead of "the", "a", or other adjectives. Is there a way to do so?

https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Obesity%20or%20excessive%20expansion%20of%20the%20adipose%20tissue%20is%20a%20consequence%20of%20chronic%20energy%20imbalance%20between%20energy%20intake%20and%20dissipation.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1